# Extended Status Bar moves app view down (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know if I am missing something, but here is what I am seeing when running on an iPhone 6p with iOS 9:

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` gives me a rectangle `{0, 20}, {414, 716}`

and

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` gives me `{0, 0}, {414, 736}`

I create my UIView programmatically so I make it {414, 736} but leave the top 20px alone since the UIView goes behind the status bar. Now, if I enable a hotspot and I connect a device, the status bar becomes taller, so now I get:

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] = {0, 40}, {414, 696}`

and

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] gives me {0, 0}, {414, 736}`

However, my UIView seems to be partially under the status bar now, i.e. if I do the same method as before and try to create a 736-tall view and leave the first 40px empty, I get cut off at the bottom, by about 20 pixels. That makes no sense to me, I can't see a way to know how much the status bar "pushes" the view down, I don't want to be checking for a height==40 and hardcode the solution.

Have I missed something in the docs?

Edit: Maybe I did not explain it well enough. Suppose I add a green rectangle with origin (0,0) size (20,40) to self.view. When the status bar is not extended, I can see it go behind the status bar, starting at (0,0):

[image: regular status bar]

So if I wanted to position it below the taskbar, I would have used [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].origin.y or the status bar width property and that would add 20px, or the size of the status bar. When the status bar changes to the extended, the [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].origin.y and status bar width become 40px, so you'd think you still would add this to position something. However, it seems that your top view now inexplicably (to me) stars at 20px from the screen top, so adding a 40px box at (0,0) as before draws only half of it behind the status bar (the image is the same height as before, i.e. the green box moved down):

[image: extended status bar]

So if I added [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].origin.y to my item positioning they would now go 20px lower than I would expect them to. I can check for the width of the status bar and change the behavior accordingly, but that sounds silly to me. There should be a way for me to know what part of my view the status bar is REALLY overlapping and what height is left to me. So, the status bar seems to be overlapping 20px for both the regular and extended status bar, but in the latter case my top view loses another 20px in available height and I can't see a way to get that from the system.

Comment: Why don't use use the `applicationFrame` instead of `bounds`? The `applicationFrame` takes into account the status bar regardless of its size.

Comment: My problem is that applicationFrame seems inconsistent between regular status bar and extended. While it shows me the size correctly of the status bar, the regular status bar is overlayed over my view, while for the extended one only HALF of it is overlayed over my view. How can I know that programmatically?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am running in to the exact same scenario, and no amount of updating views seems to help. Just a testing note - if I have the extended status bar already up when I launch, everything lays out fine. I am thinking maybe this has something to do with the topLayoutGuide.

Comment: still no solution for this?